# Reading strings in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to modify my function that strips the  tag from the value of a database record in the title of French pages:

```
Function removeSup(strToRemove)
    strToRemove = Replace(strToRemove,"<sup>","(")
    strToRemove = Replace(strToRemove,"</sup>",")")
    response.Write(strToRemove)
End Function
```

so that it can read the contents of the tag. If the contents is a ® or a ™, then do nothing, but if it's MD or MC, then do the replace.
I just haven't figured out how to read strings with VBScript so is this something that I should do with VBScript or have it passed to jQuery to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with Regular Expressions but if i understand what you mean the you can do it as below.
Jquery is javascript only, if this is for web, best not to mix vbscript and javascript unless realy necessary.

```
Function removeSup(strToRemove) 
    strToRemove = Replace(strToRemove,"<sup>MD</sup>","(MD)") 
    strToRemove = Replace(strToRemove,"<sup>MC</sup>","(MD)") 
    response.Write(strToRemove) 
End Function
```